# How to import multiple Git projects at once in Eclipse (egit)?

Tags: git, eclipse, batch-file, import, egit

I am a teacher. For an assigment, each student codes a Java app with Eclipse and commits his project into a Git repo. They then share this repo with me (only).

When I mark the assigments, in Eclipse I have to repeat the following for EACH student : Import/Project from Git + provide the student's URL + click on all the Next buttons. I have 55 students.

Is there a way I could batch-import all the projects at once in Eclipse?

Comment: In the _Git Repositories_ view right-click the repository and choose _Import Projects..._.

Comment: If they've committed the .project file into their repositories, and all of the clones (cloned from the CLI, possibly scriptable) are under one directory, the Existing Projects import should find them by searching under that one directory.

Comment: Theses suggestions imply that the students's repositories have already been cloned at some point. But that is precisely my problem : when I start marking, I start with an empty workspace, and I have to provide one by one each student's git url to clone them for the first time (such that they appear in my c:\users\myself\git directory ). I would need the ability to provide Eclipse with a liste of URL to "import from git" all at once somehow....

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a clarification of nitind's comment.

I assume that your local clone to your desktop of all 55 repositories is in a single root directory, like "C:\Users\yourself\git" (Mac would be similar, but a different path).  If you have other repositories in that same root directory, it will be a small annoyance to this process, but not a huge problem.

Simply select "File->Import...->Existing Projects Into Workspace", then on the "Browse..." button next to "Select root directory", select your "C:\Users\yourself\git" directory.  All of the repositories will (hopefully) be detected as projects, and you could "Select All" (unless some of them have to be unselected), and then confirm, and then wait likely quite a while for it to import and build all of those projects.

Comment: "Import Existing Projects Into Workspace" has nothing to do with Git. It imports multiple **eclipse** projects, whatever natures they have (so, when you have the .project files)